# why would C++ reorder members of a class with different access control?

Tags: c++, class, layout

According to the C++ standard:
*The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified.*

and using operator offsetof do produce a warning under gcc when I have data members with different access control.

out of curiosity: why would a compiler do that ?

Comment: To better pack the data so as to have less padding.  Or to better order the data so as to have better performance.

Comment: If the compiler is permitted to do that, the compiler can do code analysis and determine that the existing access pattern of class members can be optimized to take advantage of hardware-specific features. For example, if both a private and a public class member is frequently accessed together they'll benefit from sharing the same cache line.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is there any compiler that actually does that?

Comment: It's worth noting that this is expected to change. C++23 won't allow this.